# Reboot linux server with no root filesystem mounted

Tags: linux

I was recently asked the following question:

> How could you reboot the linux server if your root filesystem is not
>   mounted and you cannot mount it (it is lost) and you do not have any
>   binary - you have only root shell.

It has something to do with /proc I assume, but maybe it is not possible at all. Could anyone provide some guidance on what I should do in that situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the root file system, and as it was specified in the question,  you don't neither have binary, I think that echo will not work, so the only solution is a hardware keyboard interrupt using indeed as said it @Pazi the SysRQ Magic Keys.

To do so, you should do: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen / SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>some key</kbd>

Here, it would be: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen / SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (where <kbd>b</kbd> will *immediately reboot the system, without unmounting or syncing filesystems*).

For additional magic keys and what they do, see [Wikipedia: Magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). Also note that non-QWERTY layouts may use other physical keys.

Comment: echo will work, as it's also a shell builtin (I know for bash and dash). Try it by moving the echo binary out of the `/bin` folder.

Comment: this is expected to be a builtin binary but in some case of some distribution, is not (exotic distribution I know), so it could be usefull to also now that keyboard interrupt do the trick.

Comment: Indeed, both ways are the way to go :)

Comment: Yep, you're right ;-)

Comment: I did not know anything about these magic keys, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can reboot with magic sysrq key:

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

For more information read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) or [kernel documentation](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt).

`echo` is also a shell built-in command (known in bash and dash for me) and used if `/bin/echo` is not available.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I believe that `echo` (at least in `bash` and `dash`, at least on all GNU/Linux systems I've encountered) is used over `/bin/echo` even if the latter exists. You have to provide an explicit path to use the external binary. (This is especially important with `dash`, since its builtin `echo` doesn't support many of the arguments - but that's not relevant here).

Comment: @Bob: Well, the trouble with `echo` is that there are many variations. There are two basic flavors, one taking options `(`-n`, `-e`) and one taking special characters and than each variant may have or not have individual features.

Comment: Ok, my try which echo was used was with `which`. If the binary exists, which outputs the binary, if not not.

Comment: @Pazi Use `type` to also list shell builtins. The `-a` option will show all matches.